# Passing Java to Javascript takes a long time

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, tomcat

I am trying to pass a big JSONObject to Javascript through a HTTP request (sent using Java Tomcat).

But passing the Object from the Java variable to the Javascript variable is taking forever when the JSONObject size grow

How I do:
In the Java servlet I set the attribute I want to pass using Java HttpServletRequest, and call the page I want:

```
request.setAttribute("myJsonAttr", myJSONObject);`
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then I retrieve the JSON object in the target JSP :

```
<% 
  JSONObject myJavaJSONObject = (JSONObject) request.getAttribute("myJsonAttr");
%>
<script>
  var alignmentJson = <%=myJavaJSONObject%>;
</script>
```

Usually it works fine. But it won't stop running for JSONObject with more than 100 000 entries: it blocks at `var alignmentJson = <%=myJavaJSONObject%>;`

I need to get this JSON Object to exploit it using Javascript (AngularJS)

Is there a better way to pass a JSON Object from a Java servlet to Javascript?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: the page stop responding after calling the Java JSONObject.

Does the Java only try to retrieve the object after it has been called? I also tried to log the `myJavaJSONObject.toJSONString()` directly in Java (before passing it to the javascript). And, in this case, the crash occures when `myJavaJSONObject.toJSONString()` is logged

Here an example with log displaying:

```
<% 
  JSONObject myJavaJSONObject = (JSONObject) request.getAttribute("myJsonAttr");
%>
<script>
  console.log("this log is displayed");
</script>
<script>
  console.log("this log is not displayed");
  var alignmentJson = <%=myJavaJSONObject%>;
</script>
```

Comment: What is the actual bottleneck in the operation?  There are a variety of things you can do, for example fetching your data dynamically from the client-side page with AJAX (probably in chunks instead of all at once).  But how you'd design that and the impact it would have on performance depends on what's actually causing the performance problem.

Comment: I edited the post: the bottleneck is at `var alignmentJson = <%=myJavaJSONObject%>;`
When myJavaJSONObject size goes up it won't stop processing

Comment: All that line does is set a variable.  Do you mean that the bottleneck is actually transferring the data from the server to the client?  Paging the data via AJAX seems like an ideal approach then.  It's a bit broad, but overall the idea is that you wouldn't send any data to the page when it initially loads, but the page itself would contain JavaScript code to fetch data from the server.  So the page would load quickly, and would then start fetching the data after it loads.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the problem comes from the data transfer (server to client).
The page stop responding after the first call to the "myJavaJSONObject" (I edited the main message)